# How to extend Bootstrap 4.1 $spacers with additional sizes

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

The [Bootstrap 4.1 documentation on spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/) says that I can extend the $spacers variable (which is used by the margin and padding classes) but it doesn't explain how.

Can anyone share a link to official documentation? If that doesn't exist can anyone explain?

Answer (score 11):

You can follow Bootstrap's [Variable defaults](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults) documentation for how to override the default for just a single Sass variable. You can add your own by setting `$spacers` in your override file:

```
// Your variable overrides
$spacer: 1rem;
$spacers: (
  6: ($spacer * 3.5),
  7: ($spacer * 10)
)

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

The variable the docs refer to is called `$spacers` and is in [_variables.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/54d86e6249d90fa8634acd3bc0b78556269edce5/scss/_variables.scss#L122-L141):

```
// Spacing
//
// Control the default styling of most Bootstrap elements by modifying these
// variables. Mostly focused on spacing.
// You can add more entries to the $spacers map, should you need more variation.

$spacer: 1rem !default;
$spacers: () !default;
// stylelint-disable-next-line scss/dollar-variable-default
$spacers: map-merge(
  (
    0: 0,
    1: ($spacer * .25),
    2: ($spacer * .5),
    3: $spacer,
    4: ($spacer * 1.5),
    5: ($spacer * 3)
  ),
  $spacers
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using **Sass**, you simply add another entry to the $spacers variable before compiling bootstrap. So something like:

```
$spacers: (
  0: 0,
  1: ($spacer * .25),
  2: ($spacer * .5),
  3: $spacer,
  4: ($spacer * 1.5),
  5: ($spacer * 3),
  6: ($spacer * 5)
)
```

I hope it's helps ;)